# Sinch Audio and Video Calling in Android

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am trying to use sinch audio and video calling in android but problem is that how to check that the incoming call is audio or video . I am using shared preference for that purpose.Video to video call works fine on both side and when incoming call is audio on other side video incoming call activity called instead of audio in other user phone. Any help would be Appreciated.

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

    //set the shared preferences
    private SharedPreferences mPickSharedPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mPickSharedPrefsEditor;

    private static final String APP_KEY = "*******************";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "****************";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";

    public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";

    static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient mSinchClient;
    private String mUserId;

    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


        super.onCreate();
        mPickSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("mPickSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mPickSharedPrefsEditor=mPickSharedPrefs.edit();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void start(String userName) {
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mUserId = userName;
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName)
                    .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                    .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

            mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            // Permission READ_PHONE_STATE is needed to respect native calls.
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().setRespectNativeCalls(false);
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public Call callUserVideo(String userId) {
          //  mPickSharedPrefsEditor=mPickSharedPrefs.edit();
            mPickSharedPrefsEditor.putString("call_status","1");
            mPickSharedPrefsEditor.commit();
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUserVideo(userId);
        }

        public Call callPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        }

        public Call callUser(String userId) {
          //  mPickSharedPrefsEditor=mPickSharedPrefs.edit();
            mPickSharedPrefsEditor.putString("call_status","0");
            mPickSharedPrefsEditor.commit();
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId);
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return mUserId;
        }

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public Call getCall(String callId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
        }

        public VideoController getVideoController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getVideoController();
        }

        public AudioController getAudioController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call");
            Log.d(TAG,call.getRemoteUserId());

            mPickSharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences("mPickSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mPickSharedPrefsEditor=mPickSharedPrefs.edit();
            String Check_Call_Status;
            Check_Call_Status=mPickSharedPrefs.getString("call_status","");
            Log.d(TAG,Check_Call_Status);
            if(Check_Call_Status.equals("1")) {

                Log.d(TAG,"Video Call");
                Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
                mPickSharedPrefsEditor.clear();
            }
            else
                if(Check_Call_Status.equals("0"))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Voice Call");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, VoiceIncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
                    mPickSharedPrefsEditor.clear();


                }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did audio and video calling simultaneously using this below code. 
In SinchService

```
private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

    @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {

        if (call.getDetails().isVideoOffered()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming video call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, VideoIncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming audio call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already try this but didn't work. However Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you use separate Sinch Service classes for both audio and video?

Comment: and did you use public Call callUserVideo(String userId) {},  public VideoController getVideoController() {}  and public AudioController getAudioController() {} methods in Sinch Service class.

Comment: i think didn't use getVideoController and AudioController but i use callUserVideo function

Comment: you have to use these methods in sinch service to enable both video and audio calling in your app.

Comment: thanks after a long time again use sinch and implement this method. work like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it like that, if its a video call you need to answer it video and if its a audio call you need to answer it like a Audio, the recipient cant decide. In the GA release we will have the possibility to not turn on the video but just audio when you are in a video call

Comment: how the sinch service decide the incoming call is audio or video automatically launch that activity. Any solution !

Comment: you can have the same if you take care of video, the think is the audio is coning in the video stream when its a video, thats why it doesnt work when when you dont listen to the add video track. you can also check in the call details on incoming call if it has video

Comment: Thanks, but i used separate button for the audio and video calling not using the one button to perform both operations.

Comment: you can still do that, but in incoming call you need to check tye of call rather tham pref for calee

Comment: ok. i'll check if i have any query than ask you again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check using

call.getDetails().isVideoOffered()

in onIncomingCall(){} function. if it returns true that mean it is a video call otherwise audio.